# Python tensorflow OOM with allocating tensor with shape[]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from PIL import Image
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
    try:
        tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0],
       [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
        logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
import os
from matplotlib.image import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
def seperate_the_data(path, mode="train"):
    try:

        os.makedirs(os.path.join(mode, 'beam'))
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(mode, 'column'))
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(mode, 'shaft'))
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(mode, 'slab'))
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(mode, 'gap_sign'))  
    except:
        pass
    beam = []
    column = []
    slab = []
    shaft = []
    gap_sign = []
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if "beam" in i:
            old_path = path+"\\"+i
            new_path = mode + '\\beam\\'+i
            os.rename(old_path,new_path)
        if "slab" in i:
            old_path = path+"\\"+i
            new_path = mode + '\slab\\'+i
            os.rename(old_path,new_path)
        if "column" in i:
            old_path = path+"\\"+i
            new_path = mode + '\column\\'+i
            os.rename(old_path,new_path)
        if "shaft" in i:
            old_path = path+"\\"+i
            new_path = mode + '\shaft\\'+i
            os.rename(old_path,new_path)
        if "gap_sign" in i:
            old_path = path+"\\"+i
            new_path = mode + '\gap_sign\\'+i
            os.rename(old_path,new_path)
def reduce_img_size(path):
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = path + "\\{}".format(i)
        img = Image.open(img_path)
        img = img.resize((320,240))
        img.save(img_path)
"""reduce_img_size("C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\DATASET\\train\\beam")
reduce_img_size("C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\DATASET\\train\\column")
reduce_img_size("C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\DATASET\\train\\shaft")
reduce_img_size("C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\DATASET\\train\\gap_sign")
reduce_img_size("C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\DATASET\\train\\slab")"""     
seperate_the_data("C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\DATASET\\1")
class myCallback(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if(logs.get('acc')>0.7):
            self.model.stop_training=True
callbacks=myCallback()
img_height = 640
img_width = 480

img_generator = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2,rescale=1./255,rotation_range=0.2, zoom_range = 0.1, shear_range=0.1)
train_ds = img_generator.flow_from_directory(directory='train',subset='training', target_size=(img_height, img_width))
val_ds = img_generator.flow_from_directory(directory='train',subset='validation',target_size=(img_height, img_width))

class_names = train_ds.class_indices
print(class_names)
batch_size = 1
num_classes = 5
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

r = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds ,epochs=15, callbacks=[callbacks], batch_size=16)

model.save("firstmodel.h5")

plt.plot(r.history['acc'], label='acc')
plt.plot(r.history['val_acc'], label='val_acc')
plt.show()
```

But it keeps raising the error:

```
2021-07-14 12:28:18.668759: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:778 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,32,638,478] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\DATASET\moonsoft_v2.py", line 102, in <module>
    r = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds ,epochs=15, callbacks=[callbacks], batch_size=16)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1183, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3023, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1960, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,32,638,478] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[node sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at \Desktop\DATASET\moonsoft_v2.py:102) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_915]

Function call stack:
train_function

2021-07-14 12:28:18.895366: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

Things I've tried to solve so far:

- Enable automatic memory growth
- reduce batch_size
- reduce image size
- change tensorflow, cuda, cudnn version.

My dataset is consists of 10.000 images which are belong to 5 classes. Still having the same issue. Same model works really fine on other devices which have NVidia RTX 2080, My graphic card is
`Nvidia GTX 1050`

Comment: Common image sizes are around 224x224 pixels, 640x480 is more than four times bigger than this.

Comment: As I have shown in the code, I have reduced the image by half of it. 320x240 is my new image size but still having the same error

Comment: update: I have reduced the image size to 224x224 and still having the same issue

Comment: Keep reducing it, you might have between 2 and 4 GB of RAM which is very little for Deep Learning

Comment: Try a batch size of 4 and keep the image size 224x224, if you haven't tried this. I had faced the same issue and I resolved it using a very small batch size. Dr.Snoopy is right, a GPU with very large RAM space is needed for deep learning algorithms.

Comment: I am sorry, I was forgetting to change img_height and img_width variables and images were always original size ahaha... 224x224 works just fine, I have 8GB of RAM